# How to create a whitelist as a smart-asset?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wave, wavesplatform, ride

I need someone to help me create a simple smart asset. I just want that you can not trade under any pair and that it can only be sent to 2 specific Waves addresses. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the list of addresses to the sender account by using [Data transaction](https://wavesplatform.github.io/waves-transactions/globals.html#data) in [Waves Console](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/smart-contracts/ride-language/waves-console-commands/waves-console-commands.html) (here I added two addresses to the Whitelist) and then broadcast the transaction to the network:

```
const DataTx = 
data(
{
data: [
{key: "3Mt2yEuqDZVSfN7jqzvtkresLRah329k2ya", value: 12},
{key: "3N17vWKRThx5eKkPLC18UjyUuFr4X3sSKCD", value: 10}], 
fee: 1500000
}
   )
broadcast(DataTx)
```

For the smart contract, you can use the [pattern matching mechanism](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/smart-contracts/ride-language/language-description.html#section-5bb5ab164c4ef874ebeb93edee236eab) to allow transfer transaction only by checking if the recipient address is defined in the sender whitelist account, otherwise the transfer transaction will not be allowed:

```
let whiteListAccount = tx.sender //In this line, we just defined the sender (in our case Bob).
match tx 
{  
case tx : TransferTransaction => let recipient = toBase58String(addressFromRecipient(tx.recipient).bytes)
isDefined(getInteger(whiteListAccount, recipient))
case _ => true 
}
```

After that you will need to compile the smart contract and set the script by Waves Console as following:

```
const Tx = setScript
 (
{
Script: compile(contract()),
senderPublicKey:publicKey(),
Fee:1400000
}
 )

broadcast(Tx)
```